# Why AWS cli being seen by one bash script but not the other?

Tags: bash

I've got 2 bash scripts in one directory. First is ran and executes:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-2 --no-include-email) # executes OK
```

second script is ran and executes:

```
configure_aws_cli() {
      aws --version
      aws configure set default.region eu-west-2
      aws configure set default.output json
      echo "AWS configured."
    }

configure_aws_cli
```

How come I get `aws: command not found` ?

I get this error even when violating DRY like so:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

configure_aws_cli() {
      aws --version
      aws configure set default.region eu-west-2
      aws configure set default.output json
      echo "AWS configured."
    }

configure_aws_cli
```

Comment: try changing to `export PATH="~/bin/aws:$PATH"`.  .... StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you just execute a script, it will be executed by child process, and your "export PATH" will die with this child process.
Try to run first process with "." or "source"

```
. ./first.sh
./second.sh
```

Comment: This gives `.: .: Is a directory`.

Comment: How come the shell export command dies out after running the script ? I thought there's no difference between running a shell command one by one or putting it into a script.

Comment: Strange thing is even if I violate DRY and put the same code from the first script into the second one I still get `aws: command not found`.

Comment: export marks variable so it will be copied to all child processes with the value on child process start.
But it will not send variable to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you, for whichever reason, run the two scripts with different interpreters.

Your script works with Bash because it expands `~` both after `=` and in `PATH`. It fails in e.g. `dash`, which does neither.

You can make it work in all shells by using `$HOME` instead of `~`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

If you additionally want changes to PATH to apply to future script, regular `source` rules apply.

Comment: Both script are ran with `#!/bin/sh` on top of the files and ran as `bash ./script.sh`

Comment: @mr_incredible Would you mind copying your DRY violating script from your post into a new file in a new directory, adding `#!/bin/sh` to the top, run `env -i bash --norc` to get a clean shell (without `~/bin` accidentally already in PATH), run `bash ./script.sh`, and make sure the problem is reproducible that way? If I do that, I get `AWS configured.` as expected. Similarly, if I just run `./script.sh`, I get `./script.sh: 8: aws: not found`, also as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing AWS command line tool using `pip` instead of pulling it from public API provided by AWS. No messing around with `PATH` was necessary.